# Saving to two models via intermediate form - Django

Tags: django, forms, required

Alright guys, I am stuck.

The problem I have is as follows:
I have two Models, `RelenvaceCodingRecord` and `EventRecord`.
The user should be able to select if an article is relevant. If it is, other fields of the form should be required, if it is not = no required fields.
This has to happen in one form, on the same page, without JS.

What I did so far is to create a form (forms.Form) that has many of the fields of the two models. Following [this](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/conditional-logic-in-django-forms/) article, I tried to implement the conditional `required` logic:

```
class CodingForm(forms.Form):
    relevance = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    event_date = forms.DateField('Event Date',required=False)
    location = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Location.objects.all(), empty_label=None, required=False)
    actors = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    party = forms.NullBooleanField('Party')
    labor_org = forms.NullBooleanField('Labor Organization')
    property_dmg = forms.NullBooleanField('Property Damage')
    violence = forms.NullBooleanField('Violence')
    injured = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    deaths = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    participants_num = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    participants_str = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    anti_gov = forms.NullBooleanField('Anti Government')
    presence = forms.NullBooleanField('Presence')
    intervene = forms.NullBooleanField('Intervention')
    brutality = forms.NullBooleanField('Brutality')
    arrests = forms.NullBooleanField('Arrests')
    issue = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    url = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CodingForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)

        if data and data.get('relevance', None) == True:
            self.fields['event_date'].required = True
            self.fields['location'].required = True
            self.fields['anti_gov'].required = True
```

In my view, then, I tried to get the form and pass its values to two ModelForms of the `RelevanceCodingRecord` and the `EventRecord` and save it all:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'coding' in request.POST:
    event_form = EventRecordForm(request.POST, prefix='event')
    relevance_form = RelevanceCodingRecordForm(request.POST, prefix='event')
    coding_form = CodingForm(request.POST, prefix='coding')

    if coding_form.is_valid():
        obj = coding_form.save(commit=False)
        event = event_form.save(commit=False)
        relevance = relevance_form.save(commit=False)

        # Relevance Data
        relevance.relevance = obj.relevance
        relevance.screened = True
        relevance.classified = True
        relevance.coder = request.user.coder
        relevance.article = paginator.page(page).object_list[0]
        relevance.last_updated = datetime.datetime.today
        relevance.save()

        if relenvace.relevance == True:
        # Event Data
            event.article = paginator.page(page).object_list[0]
            event.event_date = obj.event_date
            event.country = paginator.page(page).object_list[0].country
            event.location = obj.event_location
            event.actors = obj.actors
            event.party = obj.party
            event.labor_org = obj.labor_org
            event.property_dmg = obj.property_dmg
            event.violence = obj.violence
            event.injured = obj.injured
            event.deaths = obj.deaths
            event.participants_num = obj.participants_num
            event.participants_str = obj.participants_str
            event.anti_gov = obj.anti_gov
            event.presence = obj.presence
            event.intervene = obj.intervene
            event.brutality = obj.brutality
            event.arrests = obj.arrests
            event.issue = obj.issue
            event.url = paginator.page(page).object_list[0].source
            event.coder = request.user.coder
            event.last_updated = datetime.datetime.today
            event.save()

            redirect_to = "?page=%s" % page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            redirect_to = "?page=%s" % page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)

else:
    coding_form = CodingForm(prefix='coding')
    coding_form.fields["location"].queryset = Location.objects.filter(ccode=country).order_by('name')
```

This, however, does not work: No Records are created in my database, I only get redirected.
Is there a way to make this work, at all? Or am I on a fools errand here?
Most of the data passing from one form to the other is not DRY as well, but I don't know a better way.

**Any** help here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens here when you say it does not work?

Comment: I get redirected (as I should), but there are no RelevanceCodingRecords or EventRecords created in the database.

Comment: I am not sure about calling coding_form.save() since this is not a ModelForm and not linked with any model. Could you try just using coding_form.cleaned_data dictionary for all the values from coding_form?

Comment: you have `obj = coding_form.save(commit=False)` but never actually save it anywhere later on

Comment: @maulik13 That was indeed the solution! Could you post this as an answer? Then you get rep out of it :)

Comment: @LukasKawerau Posted it as an answer thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `coding_form` is not an instance of ModelForm and hence `coding_form.save()` will not work and will not return a model instance. You can access form data by using `coding_form.cleaned_data` dictionary.